# Problem with handling with many small similar datasets

Tags: python, data-structures, data-science

I have a dataset with historical sales of products within some chains. It looks like:

```
date       | customer | store | warehouse | product | volume, units
2000-01-01   customer1  store1  warehouse1  product1   10
2000-01-02   customer1  store1  warehouse1  product1   6
...
```

I want to do preprocessing with the dataset and work with each key (unique combination of a customer, a store, a warehouse, and a product) as a separate dataset because it takes some computational time to filter the key, preprocess it and put it back into the dataset.

Putting the keys into separate datasets might solve the problem, but as I have a large number of keys (~200K), it doesn't look like the right way.

I thought about dask, but I haven't found the way to set manually how to define buckets by keys. So, I'd like to address to each key like a separate dataset, but don't want to just save them into separate files. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running into coding issues? Please share code sample of progress you've made and where you're stuck.

Comment: No, the code works fine, my question is more general: are there any more efficient ways to keep the datasets in RAM and access them without filtering and aggregation?